# Why set display: block when onmouseover via for loop on all elements, no only one?

Tags: for-loop, onmouseover

```js
var priceListItem = document.getElementsByClassName("priceListItem");
var priceListItemCirclePrice = document.getElementsByClassName("priceListItemCirclePrice");

for(var i = 0; i < priceListItem.length; i++){
priceListItem[i].onmouseover = funckiaNefunkcia;
function funckiaNefunkcia(){
    
    for(var a = 0; a < priceListItemCirclePrice.length; a++){
        priceListItemCirclePrice[a].style.display = "block";
    }

};

priceListItem[i].onmouseout = funckiaNefunkciaLeave;
function funckiaNefunkciaLeave(){
    
    for(var a = 0; a < priceListItemCirclePrice.length; a++){
        priceListItemCirclePrice[a].style.display = "none";
    }

}
}
```

```html
<div id="priceList">
        <div class="container">
        <div id="sectionName">Cenník</div>
            <div class="row text-center" id="priceLists">
                <div class="col-md-3 priceListItem">
                    <div class="priceListItemTop">
                        <h4>Strih dlhé vlasy</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="priceListItemBottom">
                        <ul style="text-align: left">
                          <li>strih podľa požiadavky</li>
                          <li>umytie vlasov</li>
                          <li>vlasová kozmentika</li>
                          <li>procedúry</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="priceListItemCirclePrice">
                        <p>30 EUR</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 priceListItem">
                    <div class="priceListItemTop">
                        <h4>Strih krátke vlasy</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="priceListItemBottom">
                        <ul style="text-align: left">
                          <li>strih podľa požiadavky</li>
                          <li>umytie vlasov</li>
                          <li>vlasová kozmetika</li>
                          <li>procedúry</li>
                          <li>farbenie vlasov</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="priceListItemCirclePrice">
                        <p>40 EUR</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 priceListItem">
                    <div class="priceListItemTop">
                        <h4>Spoločenské príležitostné účesy</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="priceListItemBottom">
                        <ul style="text-align: left">
                          <li>strih podľa požiadavky</li>
                          <li>umytie vlasov</li>
                          <li>vlasová kozmentika</li>
                          <li>doplnky do vlasov</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="priceListItemCirclePrice">
                        <p>50 EUR</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 priceListItem">
                    <div class="priceListItemTop">
                        <h4>Individuálne požiadavky</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="priceListItemBottom">
                        <ul style="text-align: left">
                          <li>strih podľa požiadavky</li>
                          <li>umytie vlasov</li>
                          <li>vlasová kozmentika</li>
                          <li>procedúry</li>
                          <li>farbenie vlasov</li>
                          <li>doplnky do vlasov</li>
                          <li>iné požiadavky</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="priceListItemCirclePrice">
                        <p>70 EUR</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Element by class name priceListItemCirclePrice is display: none, I want to set display: block after onmouseover on priceListItem. Now when I do onmouseover on the priceListItem it show all priceListItemCirclePrice, on all 4 elements.

I need to change style to display: block on only one element - I´m currently mouseover.
Thank you

Comment: Hi @Jakub8 - please edit your question to show what happens, and explain what you expected to happen. Have a look at how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Reading your question, I do not really understand what the problem is.

Comment: I did my best :) @tucuxi can u pls help?